# Running Vagrant in windows server 2016 standard

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, windows-server, vagrant-provision

I was trying to bring up a Oracle Linux instance in the windows server 2016 VM . I have installed Vagrant and VirtualBox in Windows Server 2016 Standard. Vagrant got installed, and I was tryng spin up a instance using virtualbox as provider, but I was popped with the below error. Can someone throw out some lght on this?

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The native API dll was not found (C:\Windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Thanks,
Mawy

Comment: I remember stumbling into something similar last year working with vagrant and kubernets, I believe at the end was some compatibility issues related to windows and my board's virtualization config, I think to solved it I had to run it natively on a Linux machine (made a bootable disk on my pc)

Comment: Hi , as like you were  also running vagrant on top of a windows server or on a windows 10 operating system Becuase I was facing this issue in my windows 10 and  able to resolve it, but with the windows server , and am not able to. Thinking its a kind of limtation with Vagrant, but to substantiate I cannot find any doc link to confirm it.

Comment: reviewing some of my notes at the time (this was more than a year ago) my problem was that vagrant itself was creating a container, then my virtual infra was trying to be run inside that container, but on windows isn't possible to have this kind of virtual "matryoshka", the only solution was to run it from Linux box, what I remember is that I didn't found the info but have to dig the issue my self, if this makes sense let me know to post it as an answer

Comment: bottom line, in my experience you basically hit a brick wall related to low-level OS limitations

Comment: yeah, it seems like a limitation with Windows Server box

Comment: gald you fount the issue, will redact some kind of answer later I think many people have stumble into this problem